# Get image location after redirect with CORS enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cors

I'm trying to get the redirected URL of an image from an external server with CORS enabled, this can't be done on the server due to the react app not having a central server, I am not in contorl of the remote server. The content of the image doesn't really matter, just the URL.

Here's what the response headers are

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true 
Content-Length  170 
Expires -1
Location    http://someimage.com/png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your React app to get the content of the `Location` header, you can fetch the URL, and get the headers from it. [See this documentation about Fetch response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers).

Here is an example from this page :

```
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.headers); // returns a Headers{} object
});
```

You can find some documentation on the Header class [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers).

If you are not using `fetch`, you can probably access the response headers from the API you are using (`XMLHttpRequest` or `axios` for example).

---

However, if what you want is to get the image from a URL, knowing that this given URL is redirecting (with a `301` status code and this `Location` URL for example), then you can just call this URL. The browser will take care of following the redirection automatically.

Comment: This gets blocked by the browser sadly. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: `The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://someimage.com/png. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: Then you are probably not allowed to access the ressource. This security is intended, and has the goal of preventing unauthorized sources from accessing this data.